# Android: How to log in a website

Tags: android, forms, authentication, android-asynctask

I am learning how to log in a website, but I still can't do it successfully.

It seemed not log in successfully because the return html content is still the login page instead of the successful login page.

I chose the website to practice, the following is my core code. Thanks a lot.

```
public class TestAyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private final String url = "http://dinbendon.net/do";
    private DefaultHttpClient client;
    private String CAPTCHA; 
    private String strResult; 

    public TestAyncTask() {

        client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        initial(url);                   

        List<NameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "guest"));      
        list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "guest"));
        list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("result", CAPTCHA));

        try {

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(list, HTTP.UTF_8));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpPost);
            if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {

                strResult = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());

                Log.d("Test", strResult);


            }

            List<Cookie> cookies = client.getCookieStore().getCookies();
            for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                Log.e("Test", cookies.get(i).getName() + ": " + cookies.get(i).getValue());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("Test", e.toString());

        }

        return null;

    }

    private void initial(String url) {

        int sum = 0;
        try {

            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream is = resEntity.getContent();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

            String line = "";
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                if (line.contains("<td style=\"width: 6em;\" class=\"alignRight\">")) {

                    int start = line.indexOf("\">") + "\">".length();
                    int end = line.indexOf("=<", start);
                    String result = line.substring(start, end);

                    if (result.contains("加")) {

                        sum = Integer.valueOf(result.split("加")[0]) + Integer.valueOf(result.split("加")[1].split("等於")[0]);

                    } else if (result.contains("+")) {

                        sum = Integer.valueOf(result.split("\\+")[0]) + Integer.valueOf(result.split("\\+")[1]);

                    } else if (result.contains("＋")) {

                        sum = Integer.valueOf(result.split("＋")[0]) + Integer.valueOf(result.split("＋")[1]);

                    } else {

                        Log.e("Test", "Not matched");

                    }

                    Log.e("Test", "sum: " + sum);

                    break;

                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("Test", e.toString());

        }

        CAPTCHA = String.valueOf(sum);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        textview.setText(strResult);
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

    }

}
```

Comment: Login Successfully... Change Username-Password, Dont post your code with Username Password

Comment: Can you log in? Use the same code? or you change something? If you log in successfully, the login page will contains the "guest" keyword in the html content. The guest/guest is an account offered by the website .

Comment: Yes I logged in successfully and i have seen page of Guest.

Answer (score 0):

```
textview.setText(strResult);
```

in `doInbackground` is not possible. You cannot update ui from a background thread.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated it, but the login problem is not solved yet.

Comment: @user3209403 what is the problem related to login?

Comment: It didn't log in successfully.

Comment: @user3209403 after you login it returns html content. you need to parse the html tags using jsoup